# Delete lines on the right of and under the longitude and latitude lines. (0° and 90°) in QGIS print layout

Tags: qgis, coordinates, print-composer

I am using QGIS. I only want the grid lines that have the coordinates 0° and 90°, and therefore need to delete the vertical line on the right and the horizontal line at the bottom. In the grid section I have only enabled the equatorial and longitude 0° and 90°, no other grid lines are activated.

[image: image showing Galapagos]

Comment: This is in the print layout correct? If so can you post a screenshot of the 'item properties' with the 'appearance' settings and if you have the 'draw coordinates' section ticked too please. Also ensure that you have no vector layers turned on.